# Do I need a database cleaner in Python?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I come from a Rails background, and am new to Python. Unfortunately, my googling and searching SO has been unsuccessful.

We are building a Python app with no framework. We're using pytest for testing, and factory-boy for factories.

I'm wondering if we need a database cleaner for our app. I have found the pytest_sessionstart and pytest_sessionfinish hooks, which would seem like a good place to do the cleaning.  But I can't figure out if we even need such a thing as a database cleaner like we use in Rails testing.

Any information or assistance is greatly appreciated! If I do need some sort of cleaner, explicit instructions or links to docs would be very useful.

Comment: Well, do you have a database and how are your setting the db up? If each tests gets a fresh db, you do not need to do cleaning

Comment: @ChristianSauer each test does not get a fresh database - that's what we are trying to set up. I was surprised there wasn't an equivalent module in Python for database cleaning, which makes me wonder if it's built into pytest or something. Please excuse me, as I said, I'm a noob to Python and thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChristianSauer I'll add more info on how we are setting up the DB to my original question, thanks.

Comment: please be more specific, add some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had similar needs, I used Pytest fixtures to do the job (or yield fixtures, which are more amenable to modern python).

E.g.

```
# without editor, so with errors
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def db():
    db = create_db()
try:
    yield db
finally:
    cleanup_db(db)

def test_something(db):
   do_ugly_things(db)
   assert false
```